# Accessing dynamically created html elements from c# code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am dynamically generating radio buttons for a list of questions, each question has at least 3 choices as answers.
I generated the radio buttons in a div called `questionsList` but I can't access them or their fieldset...
Here's my code

```
      _questions = Page.Form.FindControl("questionsList");

            foreach (Question q in _survey.Questions)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.QuestionEng))
                {
                    List<Answers> answers = _blSurvey.GetAnswers(q.TypeOfQuestion);
                    string choiceItem = string.Empty;
                    foreach (Answers a in answers)
                    {
                        choiceItem += "<input type='radio' value='" + a.AnswerId + q.QuestionId +
                                      "' name='radio-choice-v-2' id='radio" + idCount +
                                      "' runat='server' /><label for='radio" + idCount++ +
                                      "' >" + a.AnswerEng + "</label>";
                    }
                    var question =
                        new LiteralControl(
                            "<form><fieldset runat='server' class='questions' data-role='controlgroup' ID ='question" +
                            q.QuestionId + "'>" +
                            "<legend runat='server'>" + ++index + ". " + q.QuestionEng + "</legend>" + choiceItem +
                            "</fieldset></form>");

                    _questions.Controls.Add(question);
                }
            }
```

I tried to use `FindControl()` with the string question and the question's id since it is the IS I specified for the fieldset (`ID ='question" + q.QuestionId`) but it didn't work,
I also tried to access any of the dynamically generated controls but I always get null.
If my way of generating controls is incorrect, please tell me what is the best method to do so I am very new to asp.net. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plain HTML elements are *not* controls. They live entirely on the client side. However, if they're form elements (which radio buttons are) and they're inside the `<form>` tag, then when you submit the page they will be included in the values that are posted to the server, which you can access via the [Request.Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property available in a webpage (alternatively at `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a repeater and bound it to the questions list and the choices instead of generating the questions dynamically.

Like this

```
                        <div runat="server" id="questionsList" >
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestionsEng" runat="server" Visible="False">

                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion" Text='<%# Bind("QuestionEng") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblQuestionEng"
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
```

Code behind:

```
            //To bound the questions
            rptQuestionsEng.DataSource = _survey.Questions;
            rptQuestionsEng.DataBind();

            //To bound the choices
            protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
            {
              if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
               e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
              {
                 if (rblLanguage.SelectedValue.Equals("1"))
                 {
                    foreach (Question q in _survey.Questions)
                    {
                      q.answers = _blSurvey.GetAnswers(q.TypeOfQuestion);
                      var rbl = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rblQuestionEng");
                      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.QuestionEng))
                      {
                        rbl.DataTextField = "AnswerEng";
                        rbl.DataValueField = "AnswerId";
                        rbl.DataSource = q.answers;
                        rbl.DataBind();
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```